# I can't seem to scrape hrefs or text from web

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've tried various methods including searching through full xpath and finding via class then search for the href via the a tag. I've been at it for hours and I just cant seem to get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time
namelist=[]
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://waxpeer.com/")
time.sleep(15)
```

when i use .text it just doesn't work

```
search=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div/a')
print(search)
namelist.append(search)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can use `time` module give delay for loading the elements so it can find the associate tag

As you mention from this code you can extract `href` links from `div` tag `container`

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time
path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://waxpeer.com/")
time.sleep(10)
main_div=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]')
for divs in main_div:
    links=div.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    for link in links:
        print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Output:

> https://waxpeer.com/sport-gloves-vice-field-tested/item/21642893513
> ...

Comment: Thank you so much man, do you think this will work for hrefs too?

Comment: @JoshMurphy try it i guess it should work!

Comment: For some reason it does not work for href links. I am not usd o selenium tho. I can get the href links for stuff like the social links but i cant get it for the items

Comment: can you update your code for what you tried or point which href you want to scrap so it will better to understand

Comment: I have updated the code is it hard to understand?